# Programmatically access HTTP endpoint in dotnet core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am curious if it is possible to directly fire off a request to the HTTP request handlers in a dotnet core (2.2) program (i.e., with a method call).  I know I can use HttpClient to make an actual HTTP request to another (or the same) server:

```cs
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.coolurl.com");
```

But what I really want to do is make an HTTP call to one controller endpoint from some other location within the same dotnet project.  Is such a thing possible?

If anyone is interested, the use case is to create something similar to feathers.js, where the a SignalR hub automatically provides access to the same functionality as the HTTP endpoints already defined in the project.  So basically if I have an HTTP controller with an endpoint already defined for POST /api/things, I would like to be able to call a SignalR hub method like:

```js
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
              .withUrl("http://www.coolurl.com/realtime")
              .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
              .build();
let response = await connection.invoke("POST", "/api/things", JSON.stringify({jsonBody: "payload"}))
```

and receive the same response as I would have by making an AJAX request to the HTTP rest API.

Comment: There's nothing (much) stopping you calling your own API using an HttpClient, although usually it's going to be more efficient to not do so and instead invoke the internal methods directly. You will need to decide whether to use localhost or the external address; if external you could be adding a few extra network hops to your traffic and could have firewall issues, both in and out.

Comment: @sellotape, thanks for the comment. I do have some code that calls my own API using HttpClient (on localhost).  The only thing stopping me from using this in production is the fear of my colleagues' ridicule (also I know I would have a tiny bit of latency, and perhaps more importantly, extra memory usage by receiving data in SignalR, then transferring via the "internal" HTTP request). Do you know how I "invoke the internal methods directly"?  I can write a hub that calls the same methods that my controllers do, but then I have two codebases to keep in sync that do basically the same thing.

Comment: Your controllers and hubs should be as simple as possible. The common logic should be implemented in separate class that will be used by controller and hub.